# How to call PostgreSQL stored procedure from EF Core?

Tags: postgresql, function, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to call a function I wrote from database but the result is -1 please help

Database : Postgresql

```
var result = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw($"select * from subunit({unitId})");
```

Comment: `ExecuteSqlRaw` is for DDL/DML (`INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/ALTER/CREATE`), not `SELECT` queries. Use `DbSet<T>.SqlQuery` to bind a raw SQL query to an entity-typed result set, or `Database.SqlQuery()` for non-entity-type queries.

Comment: or just read this: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/raw-sql-query-in-entity-framework.aspx (ignore the fact the URL says EF4.3, it's really for EF Core 6)

Comment: in que you said function but you are executing select query, doesn't match with question

Comment: @CodingMytra i used select query to call postgresql function but i think wrong

Answer (score 0):

Function class

```
[Keyless]
public  class SubUnit
{
 
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    
}
```

We added the following reference to the DbContext class

```
 public virtual DbSet<SubUnit> SubUnits { get; set; }
```

Called function code

```
    public IEnumerable<Unit> GetSubUnitByParentId(long unitId)
    {

        var result = _context.SubUnits.FromSqlInterpolated($"select * from subunit({unitId})");

     
        return result;
    }
```

its run succesfull.